# O caractere nulo \0 é colocado automaticamente no fim da string ou não coloca porque limitei o scanf()?

Tags: c, string, null, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char nome[20];
    char sobrenome[20];
    char nomeSobrenome[40];

    printf("Insira seu nome e seu sobrenome:\n");
    //scanf("%s%s", nome, sobrenome);
    scanf("%[A-Z a-z 0-9 !-_]s", nomeSobrenome);

    //printf("%s %s", nome, sobrenome);
    printf("%s\n", nomeSobrenome);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isto dá para ver a fazer debug do programa. Sim vai colocar na mesma o `\0`, é um indicador para saber onde termina o texto, porque senão ao escrever `ola` numa string `sobrenome[20]` ia deixar 17 espaços de lixo e ia imprimir isso

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi muito bem sua resposta. O tamanho do vetor, neste exemplo, não é o foco. O que eu desejo saber é o seguinte: se eu limitar o scanf, o programa automaticamente coloca o caractere nulo? Eu sei que ele coloca automaticamente sem limitar o scanf. A dúvida é com a limitação. Abraço.

Comment: A minha resposta diz isso. "Sim vai locar na mesma o `\0`"

Comment: Eu fiquei em dúvida porque o \0 vem antes do !, na tabela ASCII.

Comment: Apenas está a limitar o `scanf` ou seja, o que ele vai ler. Porque achava que nao ia meter o `\0` ??  O `\0` é colocado DEPOIS de ter lido, depois do `scanf`....

Comment: Tem razão, sanou minha dúvida! Não pensei na ordem. Valeu!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode testar por conta própria:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char nomeSobrenome[40];
    printf("Insira seu nome e seu sobrenome:\n");
    scanf("%[A-Z a-z 0-9 !-_]s", nomeSobrenome);
    printf("%s\n", nomeSobrenome);
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) printf("%c = %d, ", nomeSobrenome[i], nomeSobrenome[i]);
}
```

O `scanf()` sempre entrega uma *string* completa, o que obviamente inclui o terminador.

Não importa muito como é a formatação aplicada, este aspecto sendo perguntado não muda. O que vai mudar é como interpretar o dado entrado ou como manipular o *buffer*, mas o resultado final é sempre igual em condições normais. Este função garante uma *string* bem formada ou dá um erro (em geral o correto é verificar se tudo ocorreu bem antes de usar o dado).

Se usasse `scanf("%s", nomeSobrenome);` daria no mesmo para o terminador.

Em C não existe o tipo *string*, ele só trabalha com um *array* de `char` e isto não inclui o seu tamanho, o que foi um *design* infeliz que temos que conviver. A única forma de identificar o fim de *string* em C padrão é encontrar o terminador, portanto qualquer suposta *string* que não tenha um terminador é um erro.

O `scanf()` pode corromper a memória se não tiver um limite específico, no seu exemplo deveria ser 39 (`scanf("%39s", nomeSobrenome);`). Se alguém digitar mais que isto poderá ter problemas.

Se mandar ler mais dados diferentes, cada dado irá para uma variável e será formada com o terminador.

O que eu fiz no código acima foi imprimir todos os 40 bytes que você reservou na variável `sobreNome`. Mandei imprimir como caractere (`%c`) e em seguida como número para ficar mais óbvio (`%d`). O que vem depois do terminador pode vir qualquer coisa que já estava na memória antes.

Se usasse o `printf()` com `%s` que é o padrão pra *string* ou outra função que considera o terminador pararia o laço assim que encontre o `\0`, que é o correto em condições normais.

Para visualizar melhor e não pegar lixo de memória agora vou inicializar a variável:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char nomeSobrenome[40] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    printf("Insira seu nome e seu sobrenome:\n");
    scanf("%[A-Z a-z 0-9 !-_]s", nomeSobrenome);
    printf("%s\n", nomeSobrenome);
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) printf("%c = %d\n", nomeSobrenome[i], nomeSobrenome[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oVWgnC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bujnyolx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Terminator.c).

Comment: Ou seja, mesmo eu limitando o scanf para começar com o caractere ! (que vem depois do \0 na tabela ASCII), ele vai colocar o caractere nulo. É isso?

Comment: O nulo é algo que existe em toda *string*, não importa como formata o texto dentro dela.

Comment: @WillBill veja o [tour] a melhor forma de agradecer e identificar que era o que queria

Comment: Só um comentário: quando se declara uma string desta forma: palavra[5] = {'M', 'a', 'r', 'i', 'a'};, o caractere nulo não é colocado automaticamente.

Comment: Sim, mas isso nada tem a ver com sua pergunta.

Comment: É que você disse que "o nulo é algo que existe em toda string". No caso acima, não existe.

Comment: @WillBill isto não é uma *string*.

Comment: Entendi, um vetor de caracteres sem o nulo não  é uma string.