# Tamanho de um vetor de caracteres de acordo com seu endereçamento

Tags: c, array, c++, gerenciamento-de-memória, char

O tamanho de um vetor de caracteres é dado pelo seu endereçamento ou pelo valor da variável? Exemplo:

```
char[1000] = "Exemplo Teste"
```

O tamanho desta variável é de 1KB devido ao seu endereçamento `char[1000]` ou o tamanho dela é 13 *bytes* devido ao seu conteúdo?

Comment: O C reserva o espaço de memoria de acordo com o tamanho que você definir no [], no caso vai ter 1KB. no C++ não sei informar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os termos estão errados mas para o que quer saber a resposta é que há uma reserva de espaço de 1000 bytes na memória. Apesar de isso ser detalhe de implementação, em todas implementações existentes será reservado na [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Note que isto não é 1KB, pelo menos não na forma como as pessoas conhecem. Até estritamente é, porque 1 KB realmente tem 1000 bytes, mas quando as pessoas usam KB na verdade querem usar KiB que é o equivalente a 1024 bytes.

Lembrando que você só poderá colocar 999 caracteres se quiser seguir o padrão de *string* do C, [por causa do terminador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/327101/101).

A declaração da variável (na parte entre parênteses) determina esse espaço reservado e a atribuição está ocupando o espaço efetivamente.

Comment: Maniero, eu gostaria de fazer uma variavel char com tamanho de 20 KBytes, desse modo eu deveria declarar `char[20000] = "Preencher o texto aqui com 20 mil caracteres"? Pela resposta do wellington, no momento que eu declaro a variavel desse maneira, ela já estaria ocupando 20 KB.

Comment: É muito simples, o espaço reservado será o que colocar entre os colchetes, se quer 20000 caracteres tem que colocar 20001 ali. Se quer Kbytes aí tem que por mais. Tudo isso está na minha resposta. Na verdade me parece algo estranho pra se querer fazer e não parece ter sentido fazer isto, mas não sei qual é seu contexto.

Comment: Quero testar o desempenho de um algoritmo de hash para dados com diferentes tamanhos, 10 Kbytes e 20 Kbytes, o problema é que cada caractere equivale a 1 byte, se eu tiver que preencher a variável com 20000 caracteres vai dar muito trabalho, por isso perguntei se quando coloco o 20000 entre colchetes ja aloca o tamanho de 20000 bytes para variavel, sem ter que preencher ela com os 20000 caracteres, espero ter sido mais claro agora.

Comment: Eu acho que você está querendo fazer algo sofisticado demais para seu conhecimento atual, está esbarrando em detalhes muito simples. Não tem dificuldade alguma em fazer o que quer, mas isso é outra questão, e novamente, primeiro deve aprender o básico para depois pensar em coisas mais complexas. Sugiro procurar um curso de qualidade que te dê a base (não sei indicar um), não parece que está aprendendo de forma produtiva.

Comment: @Mutante dá para fazer esse preenchimento de vetor de caracteres em uma linha (ou duas), mas creio que uma vez escrito, será um enigma tentar ler essa única linha. De maneira mais verbosa, você pode escrever em 4, aí fica legível até para quem tem conhecimento básico em programação (e nem precisa ser em C). Isso, claro, pensando em um preenchimento aleatório ou então de "_entropia aleatória_" porém reproduzível.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, pelo que vi nos comentários o que você quer saber é se quando você faz isso:

```
char vetor[20000];
```

Esse espaço é automaticamente guardado na memória para esse vetor.

Bem, o tipo primitivo char abriga 1 byte por caractere, ou seja, se você faz um vetor com 20000 de espaço, esse vetor guardará 20000 de espaço na memória para que seja usado.
Isso quer dizer que: toda vez que você iniciar o programa esse vetor vai pegar esse espaço de 20000 bytes e armazená-los, independente do seu conteúdo.
Para evitar fazer um tamanho tão grande de vetor sem necessidade você pode fazer uma alocação dinâmica de espaço através da função malloc, assim, toda vez que você inicia o programa a função aloca esse espaço dinamicamente, guarda ele, e quando você terminar e programa identificar o free:

```
vetor = (char *) malloc(20000*sizeof(char));
.
.
.
.

free(vetor);
```

Ele vai liberar todo espaço que não foi usado, deixando o programa mais leve.
Espero que tenha sido esta a dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

O tamanho dela é de acordo com o espaço que você aloca na memoria. Como é um vetor que você ja reservou o espaço vai ser de acordo com o numero que inseriu, nesse caso é 1000.