# Falha de segmentação ao printar espaço em branco C

Tags: c, ponteiro, falha-de-segmentação

Preciso fazer uma função que retorna um porteiro para o primeiro espaço em branco encontrado na string. Quando eu tento printar o espaço em branco o programa acusa falha de segmentação, o que não acontece quando eu troco *str == ' ' por um caractere qualquer, por exemplo (*str == 'b').

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char word[80];

    printf("Digite a string: \n");
    scanf("%s", &word);

    char *firstblankchar(char *str)
    {
        while (*str)
        {
            if (*str == ' ')
            {
                return str;
            }

            *str++;
        }
    }

    printf("%c", *firstblankchar(word));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Preciso fazer uma função que retorna um porteiro para o primeiro
> espaço em branco encontrado na string. Quando eu tento printar o
> espaço em branco o programa acusa falha de segmentação, o que não
> acontece quando eu troco *str == ' ' por um caractere qualquer, por
> exemplo (*str == 'b')

Sua pergunta foi editada então não sei o que escreveu e o que foi alterado.
Note que se escreveu como está no texto, `str=''` sem espaço entre as aspas no programa isso é diferente de `str=' '` que é o que você pretendia testar.

Entenda que em C `*str++` soma um no valor que está em `*str`. Se quer incrementar o ponteiro `str` para que ele aponte para a próximo letra deve escrever `str++`. No geral esses operadores `++` e `--` são mais problema do que solução, mesmo que meigos. `str++` e `++str` tem diferença sutil, com a qualquer ninguém deveria se preocupar se não usasse... Mas assim é.

#### De volta ao seu programa, e um exemplo um pouco alterado

Veja esse exemplo aqui e talvez te ajude a entender a mecânica disso em C

**O programa mostra**

```
Frase original: 'uma frase para testar o programa    '
Depois do proximo branco: ' frase para testar o programa    '
Depois do proximo branco: ' para testar o programa    '
Depois do proximo branco: ' testar o programa    '
Depois do proximo branco: ' o programa    '
Depois do proximo branco: ' programa    '
Depois do proximo branco: '    '
Depois do proximo branco: '   '
Depois do proximo branco: '  '
Depois do proximo branco: ' '
Depois do proximo branco: '(null)'
Depois do proximo branco: '(null)' :)
```

Eis o exemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* firstBlankChar(char*);

int main()
{
    char word[80] = "uma frase para testar o programa    ";
    char* proximo = word;
    printf("Frase original: '%s'\n", word);
    while (proximo != NULL)
    {
        proximo = firstBlankChar(1+proximo);
        printf("Depois do proximo branco: '%s'\n", proximo);
    };
    printf("Depois do proximo branco: '(null)' :)\n");
};

char* firstBlankChar(char* str)
{
    while (*str != 0)
    {
        if (*str == ' ') return str;
        str += 1;
    };
    return NULL;
};
```

Nesse exemplo o programa continua procurando pelos espaços e mostra na tela a string restante, até acabar a string.

Note esse folclórico comportamento do `printf()`: Quando o valor da string é `0`, o tal `NULL` e que vai sair do loop e terminar o programa ele imprime

```
Depois do proximo branco: '(null)'
```

e nunca vai saber a diferença entre isso e o resultado desse comando aqui aqui

```
printf("Depois do proximo branco: '(null)'\n");
```

Claro que nem todo compilador vai fazer isso em toda situação.

Note que em geral se vai imprimir uma string que pode ter espaços ou apenas espaços é conveniente colocar algo em volta, como as aspas que usei aqui, por razões óbvias.

Evite ficar lendo coisas do teclado antes de seu programa estar pronto. Não vai aprender nada com essas linhas de `printf()` e `fgets()` e `scanf()` e coisas assim. Mas vai levar muito mais tempo para testar seu programa...

Answer (score 1):

Tem vários problemas nesse código.

O `scanf()` tem problemas para ler textos com espaços então troquei por algo que faz a leitura corretamente.

Não faz muito sentido retornar o primeiro espaço, mas deixei assim.

Você está somando o caractere que está manipulando em `firstblankchar()` mas o que deseja incrementar é o ponteiro, então não use o operador para dereferenciar, só incremente o próprio ponteiro.

O que acontece se não achar um espaço no texto? Está retornando nada, e isso não pode acontecer, tem que retornar alguma coisa. Eu mandei retornar 0 que é um ponteiro nulo. Fazendo isso o correto é testar o retorno para ver se veio 0 e não deixar usar o dado, só se vier outro endereço é que deveria acessar o caractere desejado, então coloquei o retorno, mas deixei você fazer o teste.

Veja como fica:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *firstblankchar(char *str) {
    while (*str) {
        if (*str == ' ') return str;
        str++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char word[80];
    printf("Digite a string:\n");
    fgets(word, 79, stdin);
    printf("%c", *firstblankchar(word));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/lLDrTh). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fqrvythz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Increment2.c).

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: Por que o 79 no fgets? Já vi varios exercicios com esse 79 mas não entendi. Porque 79 e não 80 ou 78?

Comment: Podia ser outro número e pra falar a verdade eu preferia por 80, mas pra isso eu teria que ter um buffer de 81, quando só tem 80 tem que ser 79, por causa do terminador: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/327101/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136628/101